# Handler on checking if there is internet connection (all in fragment) is crashing app

Tags: android

I am having trouble finding the solution or even comprehend where the trouble could be. I went deep into it so to speak... :(

Handler

```
 mainHandler = new Handler();
    refresh = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            if (isNetworkConnectionAvailable()) {
                mListView.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                messageForChatFragment.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                sendText.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                getText.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                noInternetImage.setVisibility( View.GONE );

            } else if (!isNetworkConnectionAvailable()) {
                mListView.setVisibility( View.GONE );
                messageForChatFragment.setVisibility( View.GONE );
                sendText.setVisibility( View.GONE );
                getText.setVisibility( View.GONE );
                noInternetImage.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
            }
            mainHandler.postDelayed( refresh, 1000 );
        }
    };
    mainHandler.post( refresh );
```

method of checking the internet

```
public boolean isNetworkConnectionAvailable(){
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
            activeNetwork.isConnected();
    if(isConnected) {
        Log.d("Network", "Connected");
        return true;
    }
    else{

        Log.d("Network","Not Connected");
        return false;
    }
}
```

It's all layed inside of a fragment:

```
    @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {




    View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_tab6, container, false );
```

Here is error message:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCjos.png

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at com.mario.molitvenik.Tab6Fragment.isNetworkConnectionAvailable(Tab6Fragment.java:117)
at com.mario.molitvenik.Tab6Fragment$1.run(Tab6Fragment.java:85)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230
```

Comment: Please post stack traces as *text*, not as images.

Comment: edited post. should be ok now

Comment: Just to be on the safe side you should enclose your code in a try..catch.

Comment: It seems removing the handler after fragment has been destroyed solved my problem.


  @Override
    public void onDestroy () {

        mainHandler.removeCallbacks(refresh);
        super.onDestroy ();

    }

Answer (score 0):

`getContext()` is returning `null`, because you are calling `getContext()` at some point where `Tab6Fragment` is not attached to any activity. Your `isNetworkConnectionAvailable()` method will only work when this fragment is attached to an activity.

Comment: I understand now why it's breaking apart, thanks. Is there a way to read if fragment6 is on view or if fragment6 has context/is context?

Comment: @KristinaDujić: I do not know what you mean by that, sorry. Your `isNetworkConnectionAvailable()` method could examine the result of `getContext()` and skip its work if the result is `null`.

Comment: Thought I could add condition to handler, if fragment is out of focus don't do anything. Alright, I could do it in isNetworkConnectionAvailable() method? I will try to find the answer.

Comment: just pass your `Context` to your method `isNetworkConnectionAvailable` from the calling Fragment or Activity.

Comment: Tnx will try it out and return you!

Comment: I have removed handler after my fragment has been destroyed. Seems to be fixed and to me sounds the most reasonable. I dont want handler running in a background anyway. This is just for one fragment handler.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by removing Handler after fragment has been destroyed.

```
   @Override
public void onDestroy () {

    mainHandler.removeCallbacks(refresh);
    super.onDestroy ();

}
```